# How to get all Exchange mailboxes sizes and extract to excel using exchange shell commands?

Tags: shell, scripting, exchange-server, export-to-excel

I am running the below code to get all mailboxes sizes:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server 583606-exchange| Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft DisplayName,@{label="TotalItemSize(GB)";expression={"$([math]::round($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}} ,ItemCount  -auto
```

This is the output:

> DisplayName___TotalItemSize(GB)___ItemCount
>
> User1_________14.71 GB__________83000
>
> User2__________3.98 GB__________7600

Now if I need to export the output to excel using the below code:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server servername| Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft DisplayName,@{label="TotalItemSize(GB)";expression={"$([math]::round($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}} ,ItemCount  -auto | export-csv C:\Scripts\UserMailboxSizes.csv
```

it's exporting but no data in there.

Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance :)
Yousry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server servername| Sort -Property TotalItemSize -Descending | Select-Object DisplayName,@{label="TotalItemSize(GB)";expression={"$([math]::round($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes() /1Gb, 2)) GB"}} ,ItemCount  -auto | export-csv C:\Scripts\UserMailboxSizes.csv
```